# Laravel Auth: how does it know i'm logged in

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, server-side

I built a simple API in Laravel. There are 2 endpoints: "/register" and "/login".
If I call "/login" from my mobile app, I am...well...logged in. If, then, I call "/register" the response is "You are already logged in!". Expected behaviour, because I use Auth::check() to see if the user is already logged in.
That's my question: how does laravel know that I'm the same user that is already logged in (please, notice that I don't pass any user info in my "/register" and I'm not using a browser, so no cookies on client side I think)?

Please, notice that I'm not looking for a solution, cause the API already works as expected. I'm just curious about how Auth::check() is able to recognize a logged user even without cookies or user data.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do a token authentication

Comment: I'm sorry, my question is not clear enough. I'm not looking for a solution, cause the API already works as expected. I'm just curious about how Auth::check() is able to recognize a logged user even without cookies or user data

Comment: I believe Laravel may have different configurations for authentication, but my experience is that with the default authentication - Laravel *does* use cookies to authenticate. also how are you calling the route, if not with a browser?

Comment: I'm calling the route from a mobile app (I'm a web developer, so I don't know how it's done, I think it uses cUrl or something similar); that's why I think it doesn't use cookies

Comment: Auth::check() is able to recognize a logged in user because a session is still being created even though your application is an API.  Whatever client you are using to make the mobile app request obviously has support for cookies or else it would not work.

Comment: sorry, I missed where you said you were calling from a mobile app. I agree with @ddelnano, my experience is that if you remove Laravel cookie/s, (again it depends on what option you logged in with) Laravel will not authenticate you. Also, consider the fact its not usually enough for the Auth system to just block/deny, but it also needs to associate the requester with a user account/data and access their data etc. Also, I think, as part of Laravels anti-cookie hijacking - Laravel will re-issue a NEW cookie on *every* request

Comment: @ddelnano Oh, that's important. So it doesn't matter what client the mobile developer is using for requests, it surely has support for cookies? And it sends a cookie transparently to the server to let him know who the client is?

Comment: If your config/session.php file is configured to use cookies and the login is working as you outlined in your post then yes the client has to have cookie support or else it would not work.

Comment: Ok, last question: the client sends the cookie to the server, right? Otherwise, even if the client supports cookies, how does the server know who he is. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses php sessions to hanlde login/logout. Here is a quote from the php website about sessions:

> Session support in PHP consists of a way to preserve certain data across subsequent accesses. This enables you to build more customized applications and increase the appeal of your web site.

So here it is used to preserve the login information.

You can tell laravel where to store this session information and set various parameters for it. By default it stores them all locally on the server in the `storage/sessions/` folder. All the information regarding sessions is in `config/session.php`.

Comment: Ok, but if someone logs in with a mobile app, how does it store a session for this client? I does it recognize a mobile app from one request to the next?

Comment: This is done via api authentication (most commonly OAuth). Laravel does not provide a good way to do this out of the box, however there are various OAuth libraries for laravel that make this easy.

Comment: To expand, Auth::check() won't work in these environments. You check the token passed into each request for its validity and privilege (admin, user), then you deny access or allow access to specific routes.

In a simplistic view, api auth works as following (oauth is more complex for security reasons): 

1) user sends login information to server
2) server checks it, if it's valid, a token is generated and sent to the user
3) the token is stored in the database, and every request that the user makes that wants access to private routes must have this token.

Comment: Ok soote, that is already implemented for protected resources (I'm also using oAuth). What I miss is how Laravel Auth class (the Auth class already found in Laravel framework) is able to persist a session with a mobile app that, as far as I know, doesn't use cookies.
I mean: the app makes a request to "/login" and successfully logs in a user. After 10 minutes the app makes a request to "/register" and the Auth::check() knows it has a valid session already...but how it knows it?

Comment: As far as I know, the out of box laravel install and a mobile app without cookies cannot produce this result. If the seasion information was stored in a database or as a cookie on the phone, then this could be achieved.